# Как задать стиль всем TextView которые размещены в TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-style

Чтобы каждый раз не настраивать отображение я создал стиль `table_text`

```
<style name="table_text">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    <item name="android:padding">2dp</item> </style>
```

Необходимо чтобы ко всем `TextView` которые помещаются в `TableLayout` по умолчанию применялся этот стиль.
Как это можно настроить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через темы так:

**res/layout/main_activity.xml** (в сокращении)

```
<TableLayout android:theme="@style/Table1">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView 
            android:text="Я зеленый по дефолту темы Table1"/>
        <TextView 
            android:textColor="#0000ff" 
            android:text="Я зеленый по дефолту темы Table1, но сейчас я синий"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<TextView android:text="Я черный(?) из темы активити(приложения)"/>
```

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="Table1" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TableTextView1</item>
</style>
<style name="TableTextView1" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

**NB** Для девайсов pre-Marshmallow нужна appcompat-v7. С какого момента appcompat-v7 начал поддерживать android:theme мне не удалось найти, тестировал с `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0` - ok.

**UPD**
По поводу веса ширины и т.д.
Дело в том, что layout_ атрибуты - это директивы для родителя, т.е. для TableRow в данном случае, о том как располагать TextView внутри себя и вполне возможно они не срабатывают, т.к. когда отстраивается TableRow он не смотрит на стили дочерних элементов (by design или не доделано или оптимизировано). Таким образом, layout_ параметры следует стараться задавать в разметке непосредственно. Если в каких-то случаях эти параметры корректно берутся из стилей, то это скорее исключение, чем правило.

Comment: Спасибо! Уже хотя бы не каждому элементу задавать, а каждой таблице!)

Comment: Почему то не все атрибуты применяются к тексту по такой схеме. Например выравнивание текста по центру срабатывает, а вот гравити по центру, вес =1 и ширина 0dp нет.  appcompat-v7 вроде стоит, в грэдл - compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

Comment: @АлександрТымчук дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте это к нужному элементу разметки для применения к нему стиля:

```
style="@style/table_text"
```

Comment: У меня десятки таблиц и сотни элементов. Я поэтому и хотел задать как то централизовано для всех.

Comment: @АлександрТымчук, боюсь вам придётся это делать вручную. Просто так нельзя через стили назначить стиль к-л элементу, коий от всех остальных отличается лишь контейнером-предком